# Filter items within a particular time using count sql function

Tags: asp.net, sql, count, group-by, left-join

I would like to filter the papers sold within a particular range of time but i still don't know how can i insert the Date when the papers were ordered. Please see current codes

```
SELECT p.PaperID, p.PaperName,COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN Papers as p
ON Orders.PaperID=p.PaperID
GROUP BY PaperName, p.PaperID
```

Cuurent output:

```
PaperID            PaperName          No. of Orders
1                  Paper1             2
2                  Paper2             1
```

Database table
Sales

```
SaleID             OrderID            Amount             Date
1                  1                  10                 2013-11-10
2                  2                  10                 2013-11-20
3                  3                  30                 2013-11-30
```

Orders

```
OrderID            PaperID
1                  1
2                  1
3                  2
```

Comment: Join to sales table and before the Group By add : Where s.Date Between '2013-11-10' AND '2013-11-20'

Comment: Adding another join to Sales table in your query the using it to filter by date in a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT p.PaperID, p.PaperName,COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN Papers as p ON Orders.PaperID=p.PaperID
LEFT JOIN Sales s ON s.orderid = orders.orderid
Where s.Date Between '2013-11-10' AND '2013-11-20' 
GROUP BY PaperName, p.PaperID
```

Comment: when i tried the above query, the Orders.OrderID in LEFT JOIN Sales s ON s.OrderID = Orders.OrderID gets the error "The multi-part identifier "Orders.OrderID" could not be bound".

Comment: different error encountered. the ON here ON Orders.PaperID=p.PaperID gets the error "Incorrect Syntax near 'ON'"

Comment: it's now working but i think it only retrieves PaperID 1 even if i tried to increase the range of the date

Comment: instead of between try Where s.Date >='2013-11-10' AND s.Date <='2013-11-20'. then increase the dates and see what result you get

Comment: I get the same results. only paperID 1 is being retrieved.

Comment: The time stamp there is the date when the business transaction was made. Could you please share with me what to use?

Answer (score 1):

Adding another `JOIN` to `Sales` table in your query. Now you have `Sales.Date` column and you can use it to filter by date in a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
    p.PaperID, p.PaperName, COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders
    FROM Orders AS o
LEFT JOIN Papers AS p ON o.PaperID = p.PaperID
LEFT JOIN Sales AS s ON o.OrderID = s.OrderID
WHERE s.Date BETWEEN '2013-1-1' AND '2013-12-31'
GROUP BY PaperName, p.PaperID
```

As alternative without `JOIN` (check what has best performance in your case):

```
SELECT
    p.PaperID, p.PaperName, COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders
    FROM Orders AS o
LEFT JOIN Papers AS p ON o.PaperID = p.PaperID
WHERE p.OrderID IN (
    SELECT OrderID FROM Sales WHERE Date BETWEEN '2013-1-1' AND '2013-12-31'
)
GROUP BY PaperName, p.PaperID
```

Comment: it only returned 1 row which should have been 2 rows since i have 2 items.

Comment: Note that I'd distrust using [BETWEEN with these dates](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), as I'd expect the sales table to be using/in the future use timestamps...

Comment: I see. What would be your suggestion if ever BETWEEN should not be used?

Comment: @CharlesTan 1 row with which condition?

Comment: @CharlesTan - Always explicitly use bounded ranges as described in the blog.  Adriano - Whenever there's a date attached to a sale, I never know if it's a 'log' timestamp, or the 'business' day.  Note that I generally consider business day to be/should be derivable.  Under those circumstances, I default to assuming it's a 'log' date, and may/should have a full timestamp associated with it, at which point `BETWEEN` is unsafe.  My general opinion is that _all_ ranges are variably precise conceptually/logically, and hence `BETWEEN` should not be used.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I get your point. Yes it should be used carefully (I wouldn't avoid it if what is going on is clear).